# How to compare the values of each row with all the others in a DataFrame?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I've this dataframe in PySpark:

```
+--------+--------------------+--------------------+------+--------+----------+-----------+---+
|indirizzo           |radius|traffico|utmeasting|utmnorthing|cum_traffico|    lat_lng         |
+--------+--------------------+--------------------+------+--------+----------+-----------+---+
|PLUTO               |  5616|      22|    461680|    5064867|          99|[45.736298, 8.507]  |
|PIPPO               |  1014|      61|    422787|    4915355|          96|[44.387363, 8.030]  |
|GATTO               |  1014|      23|    346001|    4972736|          99|[44.891384, 7.049]  |
|DISNEY              |  1014|      72|    373467|    5022016|          84|[45.34023, 7.3849]  |
|LEONE               |  1014|      28|    407852|    5079131|          94|[45.859577, 7.812]  |
|HULK                |  5616|      20|    379192|    4915722|          88|[44.38471, 7.4833]  |
```

and this function:

```
def distance_haversine(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2):
    # stuffs
    return distance
```

For each row in this dataframe, I want to take the values in the column 'lat_lng' pass them as constants to the first two arguments of the function 'distance_haversine' and assign to the remaining two arguments of the function the values in the same column of all the other rows, then go to the next row and repeat the procedure. Is it possible to do such an operation without using the 'collect()' function? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Add your expected result.

Comment: Define your function as an udf, and crossJoin your dataframe to get all the combinations of lat_lng, and use the udf to get the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I see your `distance_haversine` signature, it does not match what you discribe.
So I'm offering you two different ways to do that. Assuming `df` is your dataframe.

Just to let you know, both of these method may consume a lot of ressources.

---

**Method 1 : Cartesian product**

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window as W, types as T

@F.udf(T.FloatType())
def distance_haversine(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2):
    """I created a simple distance function but you can replace it with whatever you need"""
    from math import sqrt
    distance = sqrt((lat1 - lat2) ** 2 + (lon1 + lon2) ** 2)
    return distance

cross_df = df.alias("A").crossJoin(df.alias("B")).where("A.indirizzo <> B.indirizzo")

cross_df.withColumn(
    "distance",
    distance_haversine(
        F.col("A.lat_lng").getItem(0),
        F.col("A.lat_lng").getItem(1),
        F.col("B.lat_lng").getItem(0),
        F.col("B.lat_lng").getItem(1),
    ),
).where("A.indirizzo > B.indirizzo").show()

+---------+------------------+---------+------------------+---------+
|indirizzo|           lat_lng|indirizzo|           lat_lng| distance|
+---------+------------------+---------+------------------+---------+
|    PLUTO|[45.736298, 8.507]|    PIPPO| [44.387363, 8.03]|16.591925|
|    PLUTO|[45.736298, 8.507]|    GATTO|[44.891384, 7.049]|15.578929|
|    PIPPO| [44.387363, 8.03]|    GATTO|[44.891384, 7.049]|15.087421|
|    PLUTO|[45.736298, 8.507]|   DISNEY|[45.34023, 7.3849]|15.896834|
|    PLUTO|[45.736298, 8.507]|    LEONE|[45.859577, 7.812]|16.319466|
|    PLUTO|[45.736298, 8.507]|     HULK|[44.38471, 7.4833]| 16.04732|
|    PIPPO| [44.387363, 8.03]|   DISNEY|[45.34023, 7.3849]|15.444323|
|    PIPPO| [44.387363, 8.03]|    LEONE|[45.859577, 7.812]| 15.91026|
|    PIPPO| [44.387363, 8.03]|     HULK|[44.38471, 7.4833]|  15.5133|
|    GATTO|[44.891384, 7.049]|   DISNEY|[45.34023, 7.3849]|14.440877|
|    LEONE|[45.859577, 7.812]|    GATTO|[44.891384, 7.049]|14.892506|
|     HULK|[44.38471, 7.4833]|    GATTO|[44.891384, 7.049]| 14.54113|
|    LEONE|[45.859577, 7.812]|   DISNEY|[45.34023, 7.3849]|15.205771|
|    LEONE|[45.859577, 7.812]|     HULK|[44.38471, 7.4833]|15.366243|
|     HULK|[44.38471, 7.4833]|   DISNEY|[45.34023, 7.3849]|14.898872|
+---------+------------------+---------+------------------+---------+
```

---

**Method 2 : collect_list**

According to what you said, you want to compare 1 set of coordinate with a whole set of coordinate, so your function `distance_haversine` needs to be a bit different.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window as W, types as T


@F.udf(T.FloatType())
def distance_haversine(lat1, lon1, list_lat_long):
    """I created a simple distance function but you can replace it with whatever you need"""
    return min([my_distance(lat1, lon1, x[0], x[1]) for x in list_lat_long])


def my_distance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2):
    from math import sqrt

    distance = sqrt((lat1 - lat2) ** 2 + (lon1 + lon2) ** 2)
    return distance


df = df.withColumn(
    "all_coordinates",
    F.collect_list(F.col("lat_lng")).over(
        W.rowsBetween(W.unboundedPreceding, W.unboundedFollowing)
    ),
)

df.withColumn(
    "distance",
    distance_haversine(
        F.col("lat_lng").getItem(0),
        F.col("lat_lng").getItem(1),
        F.col("all_coordinates"),
    ),
).show()

+---------+------------------+--------------------+---------+
|indirizzo|           lat_lng|     all_coordinates| distance|
+---------+------------------+--------------------+---------+
|   DISNEY|[45.34023, 7.3849]|[[45.34023, 7.384...|14.440877|
|    LEONE|[45.859577, 7.812]|[[45.34023, 7.384...|14.892506|
|     HULK|[44.38471, 7.4833]|[[45.34023, 7.384...| 14.54113|
|    PLUTO|[45.736298, 8.507]|[[45.34023, 7.384...|15.578929|
|    PIPPO| [44.387363, 8.03]|[[45.34023, 7.384...|15.087421|
|    GATTO|[44.891384, 7.049]|[[45.34023, 7.384...|   14.098|
+---------+------------------+--------------------+---------+
```

Comment: @chiraqa yes. My second solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my try with the DataFrame.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

def distance_haversine(lat1, lng1, lat2, lng2):
    distance = (lat2 - lat1) + (lng2 - lng1) # just for test
    return distance

spark.udf.register('distance_haversine', distance_haversine)

df2.alias('a').crossJoin(df2.alias('b')) \
   .select('a.*', 'b.indirizzo', 'b.lat_lng') \
   .filter('a.indirizzo != b.indirizzo') \
   .withColumn('distance', expr('distance_haversine(a.lat_lng[0], a.lat_lng[1], b.lat_lng[0], b.lat_lng[1])')) \
   .show()

+---------+------+--------+----------+-----------+------------+------------------+---------+------------------+--------------------+
|indirizzo|radius|traffico|utmeasting|utmnorthing|cum_traffico|           lat_lng|indirizzo|           lat_lng|            distance|
+---------+------+--------+----------+-----------+------------+------------------+---------+------------------+--------------------+
|    PLUTO|  5616|      22|    461680|    5064867|          99|[45.736298, 8.507]|    PIPPO| [44.387363, 8.03]| -1.8259349999999976|
|    PLUTO|  5616|      22|    461680|    5064867|          99|[45.736298, 8.507]|    GATTO|[44.891384, 7.049]|  -2.302913999999995|
|    PLUTO|  5616|      22|    461680|    5064867|          99|[45.736298, 8.507]|   DISNEY|[45.34023, 7.3849]| -1.5181679999999993|
|    PLUTO|  5616|      22|    461680|    5064867|          99|[45.736298, 8.507]|    LEONE|[45.859577, 7.812]| -0.5717209999999957|
|    PLUTO|  5616|      22|    461680|    5064867|          99|[45.736298, 8.507]|     HULK|[44.38471, 7.4833]| -2.3752879999999994|
|    PIPPO|  1014|      61|    422787|    4915355|          96| [44.387363, 8.03]|    PLUTO|[45.736298, 8.507]|  1.8259349999999976|
|    PIPPO|  1014|      61|    422787|    4915355|          96| [44.387363, 8.03]|    GATTO|[44.891384, 7.049]| -0.4769789999999974|
|    PIPPO|  1014|      61|    422787|    4915355|          96| [44.387363, 8.03]|   DISNEY|[45.34023, 7.3849]| 0.30776699999999835|
|    PIPPO|  1014|      61|    422787|    4915355|          96| [44.387363, 8.03]|    LEONE|[45.859577, 7.812]|   1.254214000000002|
|    PIPPO|  1014|      61|    422787|    4915355|          96| [44.387363, 8.03]|     HULK|[44.38471, 7.4833]| -0.5493530000000018|
|    GATTO|  1014|      23|    346001|    4972736|          99|[44.891384, 7.049]|    PLUTO|[45.736298, 8.507]|   2.302913999999995|
|    GATTO|  1014|      23|    346001|    4972736|          99|[44.891384, 7.049]|    PIPPO| [44.387363, 8.03]|  0.4769789999999974|
|    GATTO|  1014|      23|    346001|    4972736|          99|[44.891384, 7.049]|   DISNEY|[45.34023, 7.3849]|  0.7847459999999957|
|    GATTO|  1014|      23|    346001|    4972736|          99|[44.891384, 7.049]|    LEONE|[45.859577, 7.812]|  1.7311929999999993|
|    GATTO|  1014|      23|    346001|    4972736|          99|[44.891384, 7.049]|     HULK|[44.38471, 7.4833]|-0.07237400000000438|
|   DISNEY|  1014|      72|    373467|    5022016|          84|[45.34023, 7.3849]|    PLUTO|[45.736298, 8.507]|  1.5181679999999993|
|   DISNEY|  1014|      72|    373467|    5022016|          84|[45.34023, 7.3849]|    PIPPO| [44.387363, 8.03]|-0.30776699999999835|
|   DISNEY|  1014|      72|    373467|    5022016|          84|[45.34023, 7.3849]|    GATTO|[44.891384, 7.049]| -0.7847459999999957|
|   DISNEY|  1014|      72|    373467|    5022016|          84|[45.34023, 7.3849]|    LEONE|[45.859577, 7.812]|  0.9464470000000036|
|   DISNEY|  1014|      72|    373467|    5022016|          84|[45.34023, 7.3849]|     HULK|[44.38471, 7.4833]| -0.8571200000000001|
+---------+------+--------+----------+-----------+------------+------------------+---------+------------------+--------------------+
only showing top 20 rows
```